# HTML5 document drop event sometimes not triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a dragging functionality using HTML5 drag and drop api. please check small version of it in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dvc142uj/

It's working fine, but sometimes Document drop event is not triggering, this fails setting position changing.

```
document.addEventListener('drop', function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('document.addEventListener("drop"), sometimes not triggering');

    var data = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
    data.left = parseInt(data.left, 10);
    data.top = parseInt(data.top, 10);

    dragger.style.transform = '';
    dragger.style.left = (e.clientX + data.left) + 'px';
    dragger.style.top = (e.clientY + data.top) +'px';
}, false);
```

My console logs.

[image]
Always element `dragend` event firing as expected. I would like to know, how to fix this issue?

Comment: You could try using `dragend` event to cover the missing drops.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto  I think this happens only in chrome.

Comment: The drop event don't trigger only if I drop the element outside the document. It makes sense for me, does it also happens inside the document for you?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto yes inside document

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce the error. Does it still happens if you position the element in the dragend event callback?